# How to obtain width of the front side of an isosceles trapezoid?

Tags: geometry

I am a bit confused of how to obtain width of an isosceles trapezoid, the equation that the book derived was
$$b+\dfrac{a-b}{h}y$$
for the isosceles trapezoid below
[image]

I am not quite sure however how to derive this.

Comment: What is $y$ here?

Comment: What Dr. means is that $y$ has not beed defined in the picture.

Comment: By the Theorem of Pythagoras we find$$h^2+\left(\frac{b-a}{2}\right)^2=s^2$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We know that the width is a linear function, so immediately we can write that it's of the form
$$
w(y) = c_0+c_1y
$$
for some constants $c_0$ and $c_1$ (I would have used $a$ and $b$ but they were already in the picture). Notive the sign of $y$, as it grows downwards in the picture. Then we can look at what else we know about it. When $y=0$, the width is equal to $b$. So
$$
w(y=0) = c_0 + c_1 \times 0  = c_0 = b
$$
and we have already the first coefficient.

But the second coefficient is a bit trickier. We know that **when $y=h$, width is equal to $a$** (see the picture). Plugging this into the equation, we get
$$
w(y=h) = c_0 + c_1h = a
$$
we knew that $c_0 = b$, so we have the equation
$$
b + c_1 h = a
$$
with a bit of algebra, we can solve for $c_1$:
$$
c_1h = a - b \qquad \Rightarrow \qquad c_1 = \frac{a-b}{h}
$$
Now we have both of the coefficients, and we can just write the final answer:
$$
w(y) = b+ \frac{a-b}{h}y
$$